# indexOf not working when parsing JSON results from Twitter

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, indexof

I'm using jQuery to parse a JSON result from Twitter.

I'm then performing a check against the returned results to see if they contain a double quotation mark.

```
$.getJSON(url + query, function(json) {
    $.each(json.results, function(i, tweet) {
        var result = tweet.text.indexOf('"');
        if(result != -1) {
             $("#results").append('<p>' + tweet.text + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

The result is always -1.  Even if the tweet returned contains a double quot.

I also tried using:  `indexOf("\"");` and that didn't work either.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Is this an encoding issue perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twitter API returns double-quotes as `&quot;`. As an example, check out the response for this query: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=foo.

So, you'll need to use `tweet.text.indexOf('&quot;')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check encoding. %22, maybe? Otherwise, console shows that tweet.text has the quotes, right? I can see no reason why your code wouldn't work.